# SQL - updating a table using a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table of zip codes and a stored procedure to calculate all zipcodes within an X radius, given a zip code and a radius.

For example, to find all zip codes within 200 miles of 10001 I'd enter`CALL zip(10001,200)` and it would display each zip code.

In a new column "hradius", I would like to have all zip codes within 200 miles of that row's zip code.

I'm very new to SQL, thank you for any help.

Comment: You don't want to store multiple zip codes in one column, that is an unnecessary denormalization.

Comment: what flavor of SQL (Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, MySQL)?

Comment: How do you intend to store multiple ZipCodes in a single column?

Comment: @DanAndrews SQL SERVER

Comment: @DanAndrews column "hradius" would be of data type text and would look like ",10001,,10002,,10003,,10004,,...," with a comma before and after each zip code (with the exception of the first and last)

Comment: Without knowing more about your structure and app, this sounds like really bad design.  Are you calculating these lists one time?  Or on the fly each time you need it?

Comment: @user3182252 that is a very poor design as you cannot harness the power of the SQL server - you'd have to parse the string... blah.  Please reconsider your effort.  If you want to do this pre-calculated stuff, you should make these rows and not columns in the database.  Zipcode, contiguousZip, etc.  Either way, you're working on a problem that has been solved.

Comment: @BBlake I'm an intern playing around with a test database and was told this would be a good project to learn SQL, there's no app involved. I have the procedure with the formula to find the distance between zip codes, and would like to put in a new column all zip codes within 200 miles of each zip code.

Comment: It is a good project to learn SQL.  The first thing to learn is to not store multiple values in one field.  Create a related table to JOIN to.

Answer (score 0):

Don't shove a string with multiple values into one field.  Create a related table to link one zip code to multiple:

```
ZipOrigin   ZipDest   Distance
12345       23456     150
12345       34567     175
...
```

(Distance is optional - for example you could use it to find all zip codes within ANY radius less than `X`)

Comment: I wonder where he's measuring from, the center of the zip to the center of the zip (he's talking about radius after all).  So for example, if a zip is 420 across, it may "look" like the zip is over 200 miles (from center to center) however the zip could be contiguous.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, if you want to pre-generate your list of matches, you're much better off using a separate table for the matches.  You'll have two tables: one for your zip codes and one for the matches.  The second table will have two columns, one for the source zip code and one for the matching zip code within X miles (200 in this case).  There will be a separate row for each match.  The results from the stored procedure should output to the second table.  Once you have that you can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT zip.zipcode, zipJoin.zipcode
FROM zipCodes zip
    INNER JOIN zipCodeMatches zipJoin
        ON zip.zipcode = zipJoin.sourceZipCode
WHERE zip.zipcode = @zip
```

You should spend some time learning about proper table design and normalization and how to join tables together to help you understand these concepts.